# Got the error : org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory

Tags: tomcat6, ubuntu-10.04, postgresql-9.1

javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory]

i am using apache-tomcat-6.0.16,Operating system : Ubuntu, database Posrgresql9.1

my code for context.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/GisProject" scope="Shareable" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        username="khushi"
        password="ispl12345"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxActive="50"
 />
```